# Why am I getting an error when making a FragmentPageAdapter?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, fragment

Im working through a tutorial so that I can slide through tabs in my view. It requires me to make a subclass of FragmentPageAdapter - in my case:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
...
}
```

I have implemented all of the abstract methods but for some reason I am getting the following error: *There is no default constructor available in 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentPageAdapter'*

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: super(fragmentmanager) should be called in constractor

Comment: You must call super constructor: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html#FragmentPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager)

Comment: It will be great if you post more code of your pagerAdapter, at least used constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't specify any constructor in your class `PagerAdapter` , default constructor with no-args is used, which looks for a parent class no-args constructor, which is equivalent to.

```
public PagerAdapter(){
       super(); // Looks for constructor public FragmentPagerAdapter (){}
  }
```

In parent class `FragmentPagerAdapter` there is a below constructor defined

```
public FragmentPagerAdapter (FragmentManager fm)
```

Now rule in java is, once any constructor with arguments is defined , default no-args constructor is not available unless you explicitly define it. 
So here `public FragmentPagerAdapter (){}` is not there. That's why `super()` call fails to find the no-args default constructor and you get this error.

To handle this, in your class `PagerAdapter` you need to have constructor which would invoke correct super class constructor

```
public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
       super(fm);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must call super constructor: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html#FragmentPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager)

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
  // ...
  public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
       super(fm);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no default constructor available in 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentPageAdapter'

a default constructor is a contructor without parameters.
since FragmentPageAdapter has a non default contructor you are required to implement/code a constructor that matches FragmentPageAdapter.

which is

```
public FragmentPagerAdapter (FragmentManager fm){
}
```

in your case it would be like the other answers here

```
public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
    super(fm);
}
```